# jQuery upgrade issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Currently we are using `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js`
We are trying to upgrade to latest versions of Jquery and it throws of multiple issues.

We have first upgraded to higher 1.x version to make it compatible and then upgrade to `Jquery 3.4.1` version and `Jquery UI 1.12.1`.

This throws of many exceptions. What will be the best ways to follow for this upgrade process.

Comment: There are many incompatible changes between 1.4 and 3.4, you should check all the release notes. You may be able to mitigate some of them using `jQuery.migrate`.

Comment: I have tried migrate already and that does not help much

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think it would help with such a big jump.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way to know which settings are changed or deprecated.

Comment: $("#dialog-form").dialog({ is not supported.Which is the best way to replace dialog

Comment: exception thrown is Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that you have the jquery ui loaded with this `dialog` function ?